# Accessing chars in multibyte string php

Tags: php

I have mbstring.func_overload = 7 and using UTF-8. Everything works fine but this not:

```
$str = "ãçéíõ";
echo $str[0];
```

It prints a question mark in the browser.

This instead works normally:

```
echo substr($str,0,1);
```

Someone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's because you are using multibyte strings, in which a single character is represented by one to four bytes. If you select just one byte (as in `$str[0]`) you probably have only a half character selected.
`substr()` instead is multibyte save and doesn't count the bytes, but the chars.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing into the string with `$str[0]` pulls bytes out of it. It cannot be made aware of encodings, no matter that `mbstring.func_overload` has been set so. You will need to use `substr` even if it is not as convenient.

Indexing into a string is a grievous coding error unless that string represents a blob, and you just came upon the reason.